# Document oriented services in JAX-WS

Tags: java, jax-ws

Is it possible to create a jax-ws compliant end point that just receives the xml?  Basically, I want an end point class that looks like this:

```
@WebService(name = "doStuff", serviceName = "doStuffService", portName = "claimsInSoap11",
        targetNamespace = "http://services.example.com/claims/v4", wsdlLocation = "/WEB-INF/wsdl/doStuff.wsdl")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@HandlerChain(file = "dostuff-handlerchain.xml")
@Addressing
public class DoStuffEndpoint {

    @Oneway
    @WebMethod
    @Action(input = "http://services.example.com/doStuffService/doStuff")
    public void claimsIn(org.w3c.Document document) {
        // Do, you know... some stuff...
    }
}
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Raw XML From SOAPMessage in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522395/getting-raw-xml-from-soapmessage-in-java)

Comment: If you can unmarshall at least root element, then you can use `@XmlAnyElement`; see [JAXB mapping elements with “unknown” name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4280021/267197) or [Jaxb - umarshaling mixed xml element with value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4305288/267197).

Comment: I want to note that the related question "Getting Raw XML From SOAPMessage in Java" Is related, but the questions are not duplicates and the related questions answers don't actually answer this question.