# Unrecognized field using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xsd

I'have an xsd file with this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="someurl" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="someurl" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="Accesso">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Identificativo" type="idAccesso"/>
            <xs:element ref="Erogatore"/>
            <xs:element ref="Entrata"/>
            <xs:element name="ModalitaArrivo" type="modalitaArrivo"/>
            <xs:element ref="CentraleOperativa" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="ResponsabileInvio" type="responsabileInvio"/>
            <xs:element name="IstitutoProvenienza" type="istitutoProvenienza" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="ProblemaPrincipale" type="problemaPrincipale"/>
            <xs:element name="Trauma" type="trauma" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Triage" type="triageAccesso"/>
            <xs:element ref="Assistito"/>
            <xs:element ref="Importo" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="TipoTrasmissione" type="tipoTrasmissione"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Assistito">
    ... xml code ...
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="CentraleOperativa">
    ... xml code ...
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="flsProSoc">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="Accesso" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

... others ref fields ...
</xs:schema>
```

So, I've been generated java classes with jaxb2:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
   "content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "flsProSoc")
public class FlsProSoc {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "Accesso", namespace = "someurl", type = Accesso.class, required = false)
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Object> content;


    public List<Object> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

Same stuff for Accesso class and others. This is an example of my xml file which I'm tryng to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<flsProSoc xmlns="url" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Accesso>
     <Identificativo></Identificativo>
     <Erogatore>... xml fields ...</Erogatore>
     <Entrata>... xml fields ...</Entrata>
     <ModalitaArrivo></ModalitaArrivo>
     <CentraleOperativa>... xml fields ...</CentraleOperativa>
     <ResponsabileInvio></ResponsabileInvio>
     <ProblemaPrincipale></ProblemaPrincipale>
     <Triage></Triage>
     <Assistito>... xml fields ...</Assistito>
     <Importo>... xml fields ...</Importo>
     <TipoTrasmissione>I</TipoTrasmissione>
 </Accesso>

 <Accesso> ... </Accesso>
 <Accesso> ... </Accesso>
 <Accesso> ... </Accesso>
 <Accesso> ... </Accesso>
```

But when I'm going to deserializa some xml file I get this error:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Accesso" (class com.xx.yy.FlsProSoc), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "content"])
at [Source: (File); line: 4, column: 21] (through reference chain: com.xx.yy.FlsProSoc["Accesso"])

I'm using this dependencies in gradle

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.11.0'
compile 'org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.1'
```

I've tried to use:

```
(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

and with this there is no exception but also I get no data from my xml.
Can someone help to figure out the problem?

Comment: If you don't know the exact structure of `Accesso`, should it be annotated as `@XmlAnyElement`
like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278546/jaxb-mapping-elements-with-unknown-name

Comment: Does your xml schema matches the xml you try to deserialize? you can check this online https://freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html or via Notepad++. I think there is a namespace issue. In the xml you specify that xmlns="url" while in the xsd (where the root tag flsProSoc is missing) you specify xmlns="someurl". the someurl you also see in the generated code.

Comment: @martijn no the urls are the same I've just omitted here.  xmlns="http://flussi.mds.it/flsProSoc"  in xsd and in xml

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using

```
@JsonProperty("Accesso")
```

just before getContent() method in FlsProSoc class.